# arraylist remove eliminates following objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm getting a very strange action in my code. I have an `ArrayList` of the following class.

```
class mySocket 
{
    public String name;
    public Socket sck;
    public mySocket(String n,Socket s)
    {
        this.name=n;
        this.sck=s;
    }
}
```

I declare the object like this

```
ArrayList<mySocket> handler = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now the problem is that when I try to remove an item using this method:

```
public void removeByName(String name)
{
    synchronized(this)
    {
        mySocket t;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<handler.size();i++)
        {
            t=handler.get(i);
            if((t.name.equals(name)))
            {
               handler.remove(i);
               break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The remove function clears everything that follows the index.
  For Example:
if this `ArrayList` has 3 elements and I call `handler.remove(1)` it removes not only 1 but also the object on line 2.

Comment: How do you call this method? Is there any other code inside the method that removes the element?

Comment: First, you should use `t.name.equals(name)` instead of `compareTo()`, second, can you provide entire function body contains this `for` loop?

Comment: Do you by any chance have an extra `{` character on the end of the `if` line, and an extra `}` character somewhere near the end of this method?

Comment: I updated my question with the whole remove function. The problem is that it still removes everything after the index i and not exclusively it.

Comment: Per your edit: Do you have multiple threads removing elements? Could it be that they are all deleting different values?

Comment: Vivin Paliath: I do have multiples threads running but shouldn't synchronized(this) lock the class? Tis belongs to client-server applacition in which I store in this array the username and his sockets. When I call logout on the client it send this message to the server and he removes it.

Comment: @user1091446 `synchronized` only guarantees that one thread at a time executes that block. It is possible that multiple threads have executed that block using different values of `name`. Have you verified this with just **one** thread and **one** value?

Comment: Wouldn't you need mySocket on both sides of handler declaration? For example ArrayList<mySocket> handler = new ArrayList<mySocket>(); This is probably not the issue but it is still interesting.

Comment: Vivin Paliath: I tested it with only two threads (two clients connect to server) and I call "logout" in one of the clients and the array get lost. If I logout with client1 which is index=0 I lose all of the array. The arraylist.remove removes everything after the index i.

Comment: **As a side note**. Class names in Java by convention start with upper case letter. Read this: [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: @user1091446 Instantiate the array with multiple handlers. Then attempt to remove just one of them by name. This *should* work. Also an easier way to do this would be with `Map<String, MySocket>`. Then you can use `map.remove(name);` instead of iterating over the list. Also, please post your code that calls this method.

Comment: @johnsoe In Java 7 you can use the diamond operator. The generic type on the RHS will be inferred.

Comment: Show us the code where you're calling this.  It's not in a loop, by any chance?  In which you iterate through your list using an integer index, and EITHER deleting things or printing them?  Because if it looks like that, your index is simply skipping over one entry.  But this is a guess.  You need to **show us the code**.

Comment: Well just changing from an ArrayList to a HashMap solved my problem tough I still wonder why the Array didn't work. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are using an indexed for loop and removing by index. In your example, if your list has 3 elements and you remove index 1, the object that **was** at index 2 is still there. It's just now at index 1.

A better way to do what you're attempting is to use an iterator or for-each loop.

```
//code outside for loop the same
for( mySocket socket : handler ) {

    if((socket.name.equals(name)))
    {
       handler.remove(socket);
       break;
    }
}
```

Is the ordering of your `mySocket` objects important? If not, storing them in a `Map` keyed by name would save you some trouble. Then you would just call `handler.remove(name)`. This operation is safe, even if `name` doesn't exist in the map. Also, for current uses of the collection `handler` that don't care aobut the name, you can retrieve the unordered `Set` of `mySocket`s by calling `map.values()`. You would then be able to iterate over that `Set` using an iterator or for-each as above.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN NOT remove items in a Collection while looping through them, the result, as you have seen, is undefined.

You either have to build a list of items to be removed and use

```
originalList.removeAll(itemsToBeRemoved);
```

Or you build your loop using an iterator.

```
Iterator<mySocket> handlerIterator = handler.iterator();

while (handlerIterator.hasNext()) {
  mySocket t = handlerIterator.next();
  if (t.name.equals(name)) {
    handlerIterator.remove();
  }
}
```